# Need to access different variables in different methods of a Java class

Tags: java, variables

```
    package package;
        
    public class Hybrid {
        public void Summary(){
            String total = "";
        }
        public void Data(){
            String name = "";
            String last = "";
            String start = "";
            String end = "";
        }
    }
```

would like to access and set variables Summary, name and other fields using:

```
Hybrid hybrid = new Hybrid();
```

Comment: what is the use in method level fields? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Format your code here with back-ticks, not apostrophe.

Comment: What is your question? The code you show makes no sense, establishing local variable but doing nothing with them. Also, method names should start with lowercase letter by convention. To keep values around past the end of a method, you should make member fields on your class. You seem to be lacking in the basics of the Java language. I suggest you work through parts of the Java tutorial available online from Oracle free-of-cost.

Comment: What about using attributed/instance variables or returning data?

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I am purely looking at a "class" as an object.  This class contains two other objects.
Java Objects seem to have clear limits.

Answer (score 0):

This is fundamentally not allowed. You cannot access stack of a function that does not even exist at a time you want to access it. If you need access to function local values then return them from the function. If you need to preserve then in memory, then declare these variables as member fields. Example of member field:

```java
public class Foo {
    public String bar = "";
}
```

now you can access bar like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.bar = "new value";
System.out.println(foo.bar);
```

There is no reason to wrap variables in methods. If you want to access variable like `foo.subfoo.bar` then create a new class and use it as member.

---

Thank you for your feedback.
The use of the word "Fundamentally" delivered the message.
I was looking to nest interfaces or wrap methods in a class to create a basket filled with different (but related) object types.

Comment: I have my answer.
Hybrid would be a collection containing Summary and Data .
I see Java does not allow Collection of Object 
All member of a collection must be the same.

Typescript does allow collection of different objects types.